# python and elastic search update errors

Tags: python, elasticsearch, flask

today I'm updated the elastic search from 1.6 to 2.1, because 1.6 is vulnerable version, after this update my website not working, give this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from app import app, db
  File "/opt/project/app/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    es.create_index(app.config['ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyelasticsearch/client.py", line 93, in decorate
    return func(*args, query_params=query_params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyelasticsearch/client.py", line 1033, in create_index
    query_params=query_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyelasticsearch/client.py", line 285, in send_request
    self._raise_exception(status, error_message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyelasticsearch/client.py", line 299, in _raise_exception
    raise error_class(status, error_message)
pyelasticsearch.exceptions.ElasticHttpError: (400, u'index_already_exists_exception')
make: *** [run] Error 1
```

the code is this :

```
redis = Redis()

es = ElasticSearch(app.config['ELASTICSEARCH_URI'])
try:
    es.create_index(app.config['ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX'])
except IndexAlreadyExistsError, e:
    pass
```

where is wrong ? what is new on this new version ?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the following error: `index_already_exists_exception`

This means that you're trying to create an index that already exists. The second time you run your program you either need to [delete your index](http://pyelasticsearch.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#pyelasticsearch.ElasticSearch.delete) first or create it only if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm try this : try:
    es.delete_all_indexes()
    es.create_index(app.config['ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX'])
except IndexAlreadyExistsError, e:
    pass
bat in this mode i index in clean, remove all products ! :(

Comment: I don't think that [your Python library](https://github.com/pyelasticsearch/pyelasticsearch) supports ES 2.1, you should maybe migrate to [the official one](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py).

Answer (score 0):

You have handled the exception using IndexAlreadyExistsError. Try using TransportError to handle the exception.

And you can also add a check like :

```
exist = es.indices.exists(index_name)
if not exist:
    es.create_index(app.config['ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX'])
```